# Зачем передавать void в параметры функции?

Tags: c++

Очень часто вижу код

```
SomeFunc(void);
```

или же например конструктор класса, который принимает как параметр `void`.

Зачем это делается? На что указывает в этом контексте `void`?

Comment: На отсутствие аргументов.

Comment: @VTT а почему бы тогда просто не указывать аргументы?

Comment: А я вот не вижу такой код, где Вы его находите?

Comment: `SomeFunc(void);` - аргументы не требуются; `SomeFunc();` - забыл напечатать аргументы. ЗЫ в контексте С тут был бы еще один ньюанс: пустой список аргументов обозначал в нем произвольный  список аргументов, а не их отсутствие.

Comment: @VTT ну грубо говоря, если мы хотим точно указать, что в функции не должно быть параметром то можем указать `void`? 
а что же тогда делает `void*`?

Comment: А при чем тут `void *`? `void *` - это передача одного параметра-указателя.

Comment: @ixSci на форуме с++ reference очень много примером в которых встречается void в аргументе функции.

Comment: @VTT, ладно. касательно `void` я понял. а про `void *` уже почитаю, поищу. спасибо.

Comment: Значит не нужно читать этот «форум». Вы же про cplusplus.com говорите, так? С ним достаточно [проблем](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com), чтобы не использовать его. Тем более, когда есть cppreference.com. Только держитесь подальше от русской версии вышеприведённого сайта.

Comment: @ixSci окей. буду знать. спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В языке **C** объявление `void f();` означает функцию, которая принимает неуказанное количество аргументов неуказанного типа. Чтобы явно указать, что функция не принимает аргументов вообще, надо писать `void f(void);`.

В языке **C++** оба этих объявления означают функцию без аргументов. [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl25-dont-use-void-as-an-argument-type) рекомендуют *не использовать* `void` в списке аргументов.

Ссылка на интересный ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41805712/1892060.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что эта рекомендация дана без какой-либо аргументации.

Comment: @VTT, «Reason: It’s verbose and only needed where C compatibility matters.»

Comment: @ixSci А это не аргументация, это часть рекомендации. Аргументация подразумевает либо перечень объективных причин, почему использование этой рекомендации лучше, либо заявление ЛПР.

Comment: @VTT, «verbose» это отличная аргументация и объективная причина. Более того, слово «Reason» означает, что далее будет приведена аргументация, которой пользовались составители совета.

Comment: @ixSci Оценка той или иной записи как `verbose` является исключительно субъективной. Более того, она может меняться в зависимости от времени и обстоятельств.

Comment: @VTT, `foo(void)` это _объективно_ более многословная запись чем `foo()` вне зависимости от времени, фазы луны и прочих обстоятельств. Там буквально больше символов.

Comment: @ixSci Кажется вы спутали `verbose` с "длиннее".  `verbose` подразумевает "многословнее, чем можно было бы". Пример: запись `foo (void); /* функция не принимает аргументов */` где-то в библиотечном коде я могу охарактеризовать как `verbose`, потому что тут оно и так ясно из сигнатуры функции, а где-то в примере в учебнике я могу охарактеризовать как не `verbose`, потому что она явно может помочь начинающим в понимании неконсистентного синтаксиса.